# Transform iteration into function

Tags: calculus

I have an iteration like this: $x_n=1.003\times x_{n-1}-1000$

With $x_0=200000$. Plotting it would result in:

[image]

QUESTION: What is a function that would represent the same plot but then smooth? In other words, how can I transform the fixed-point iteration into a function of x?

Comment: With your numbers, what is $x_1$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I am sorry, my numbers were off. I have edited. With these numbers $x_1=199600$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $$x_{n+1}=a\,x_n+b\qquad \text{with}\qquad x_0=c$$ almost as Yannik answered, you will have

$$x_n=c-\frac{1-a^n}{1-a}\left(c(1-a)-b\right)$$

**Edit**

Since in you profile, I read *"I use Mathematica to help me..."*, I went to university to run it (I am not good with it) and I typed the following command

> > RSolve[{x[n + 1] == a x[n] + b, x[0] == c}, x[n], n]

The raw result which came out (it can be simplified) is

> > {{x[n] -> (-b + a^n b - a^n c + a^(1 + n) c)/(-1 + a)}}

Copy and paste the expression and define

> > f[a_,b_,c_,n_]:=(-b + a^n b - a^n c + a^(1 + n) c)/(-1 + a)

which is now your function. For you example, type

> > f[1.003,-1000,200000,100 Pi]

and the result $-8361.88$ will came out.

Comment: Thanks! How do you reach that conclusion?

Comment: @GambitSquared. It is a recurrence relation leading to geometric progression. Didn't you learn that stuff already ?

Comment: I only did math in highschool...

Comment: @GambitSquared. I supposed that this was teached quite early. Just google for *linear recurrence equations*. It is quite simple. Ring me back if required but I am sure you will not need to. Cheers.

Comment: @GambitSquared. Since, in your profile, you mention Mathematica, have a look at function **RSolve** an later, try $n=100 \pi$

Answer (score 1):

Note that such a function $f$ should satisfy
$$f(n) = 1.003^n x_0 - 1000\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 1.003^n$$
for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and partial sums of such power series have a nice smooth representation.

Comment: My numbers were wrong, I have edited the question...

Comment: But that summation wouldn't work for non-integer right?

Comment: Correct, but it does have a smooth extension. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series

Comment: Isn't it possible to create a function that is valid over all real numbers?